# [[item]] not work iron data table

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to execute a function using a dom-if that executes a function within an iron data table. I am able to get the function to execute without parsing a property in but when I parse item in the function will not execute.

```html
<data-table-column width="75px">
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[_isSelected(item)]]">
    <paper-icon-button icon="update"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="delete" on-tap="_deletePackage"></paper-icon-button>
  </template>
</data-table-column>
```

So I am trying to run the function _isSelected(item) however this will not run my function.

```js
_isSelected: function(item) {
    console.log("isSelected fired " + this.item.PackageName);
}
```

This function does work when I use another property so seems like an issue with item. Any ideas why? TIA

Comment: Short answer, because I'm going to bed, but Polymer is listening on "item" changing, but if you're changing item's subproperty, then you need to write `[[_isSelected(item.PackageName)`in your dom-if.

Comment: thanks for your response on this. I tried to use item.PackageName in my dom-if however when I put item.PackageName in my function it throws an error "unexpected token ." I then tried to use    [[_isSelected(item.PackageName)]] in my dom -if and    _isSelected(item.PackageName) as my function but it did not run. Any ideas? TIA

Comment: I'm pretty sure item does change when a selected row changes. I am just trying to get item data to be parsed into the function _isSelected and it doesn't seem to be possible atm

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I have time to come back to this.

Is the property `item` undefined to start with?

How is `item` set? Is it through {{item}} in item list or is it part of a dom-repeat?

I assume `PackageName` in item is something you have set of your own, in your list?

One suggestion is to declare item as follows in `properties`:

```
item: {
  type: Object,
  value = {}
}
```

and your dom-if:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[item.PackageName]]">
```

Basically, you start with an empty object, so the empty item will return `undefined` if you check item.PackageName (hence, returning `false`). Whenever you update the item, the property `PackageName` will update (returning something, which means `true`) and the dom-if will re-render.

You need to reset item if you can deselect in iron-item list.

---